Jmeter - keycloak login
I am working on an automated authentication test using JMeter, and I am trying to simulate a login process involving Keycloak. I'm trying to automate this flow:
I access my application by going to: https://mywebsite.com.
This URL automatically redirects me to Keycloak at:
https://keycloak.mywebsite.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth.
I enter my login credentials on the Keycloak login page and submit the form.
After submitting the form, I am redirected to this URL:
https://keycloak.mywebsite.com/realms/myrealm/login-actions/authenticate?
In this redirect (to the authenticate page), Keycloak sends a form with some hidden parameters, including: code, id_token, and session_state.
My goal is to intercept and capture these three parameters (code, id_token, and session_state), which are crucial to complete the authentication flow.
Problem:
I am unable to retrieve these parameters (code, id_token, session_state) from the hidden form in the redirect to the authenticate page. I’ve tried automatically following redirects using JMeter (with the "Follow Redirects" option), but it seems the values are not being captured.
I have used the Regular Expression Extractor to try to extract the values of the hidden form fields from the HTML response, but without success.
I activated the "Follow Redirects" option in the HTTP Request Sampler, but I still can't capture the parameters when the form is automatically submitted.
I verified that the variables and cookies are maintained between requests using the Debug Sampler, but I didn’t find anything helpful to solve the issue.
How can I correctly configure JMeter to capture the code, id_token, and session_state values from a hidden HTML form that is automatically submitted after a redirect?
Do I need to manually handle the redirect and extract the values from the HTML response? If so, what would be the best approach to intercept these parameters in the OIDC authentication flow with Keycloak?
Is there a better method to capture these parameters in JMeter during the redirect between requests?

It should still be possible to extract the values from the hidden inputs even if you're redirected automatically, the response is stored anyways, you need to change "Apply to" setting of the Post-Processor you're using to look into sub-samples as well:

Below you can find the example of correlating dynamic values in Keycloak-protected application using Boundary Extractor:

https://i.sstatic.net/KKG1v.gif
